# Excel - search for text and move to other cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to clean the messy address data by separate the city state and country into another cell. So i will have a list of data that want to search for it and if it match move the matched city to the city cell.

like this

[image]

Comment: You could use a combination of left(), mid() and right() to separate the parts by the spaces, then check which exists in your master list, but I think this will be vba...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You'll have to add on to these formulas once you need to start using address02 and 03 but just to give you an idea...

In `D2`:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,1/COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$G$3:$G$6&"*"),$G$3:$G$6),"")&" "&IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,1/COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$H$3:$H$5&"*"),$H$3:$H$5),"")
```

In `E2`:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,1/COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$I$3:$I$4&"*"),$I$3:$I$4),LOOKUP(1,1/COUNTIF(B2,"*"&$I$3:$I$4&"*"),$I$3:$I$4))
```

The basis of these formulas is constantly using `LOOKUP()` and I'm more or less puting together multiple of the same formulas together looking like: `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,1/COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$G$3:$G$6&"*"),$G$3:$G$6),"")` to get to the string you want.

On that note, maybe what you could do is concat all address columns into one column, create three columns behind it, e.g. City/State/Country and simply apply the short simple formula I just mentioned.

It would look like this for example:

Formula D2:

```
=A2&B2&C2
```

Formula E2:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,1/COUNTIF(D2,"*"&$I$3:$I$6&"*"),$I$3:$I$6),"")
```

Formula F2:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,1/COUNTIF(D2,"*"&$J$3:$J$5&"*"),$J$3:$J$5),"")
```

Formula G2:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,1/COUNTIF(D2,"*"&$K$3:$K$4&"*"),$K$3:$K$4),"")
```

[image]